# How to poll oldest files first using ftp inbound endpoint in Mule

Tags: ftp, mule, mule-studio

I am working on an use case using FTP endpoint in Mule.

I am expecting FTP inbound endpoint should poll oldest files first. Currently It is polling files randomly.

Is there way to configure FTP to poll oldest file(the file has been placed first in the FTP shared folder) first?

Can some one please suggest me the solution to achieve this usecase.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would have to extend the default Mule [FtpConnectionFactory](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.2/transports/ftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/ftp/FtpConnectionFactory.java) class and set your new class as an attribute named `connectionFactoryClass` in the FTP Connector. For the actual ordering you would need to extend the [Apache FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) class the factory uses, with a method that orders the file listings by timestamp. Overriding the `FTPClient.initiateListParsing()` method would probably be enough.

Comment: Thanks Anton, I have created my new class extends FtpConnectionFactory and added to FTP connector. My new class Constructor being invoked.
How can I extend the FTPClient and where should I override initiateListParsing(). Could you please share sample code if you have.

Comment: Sorry, I am no expert in the Apache commons-net libraries. I suggest you check the source code or/and create a separate question for this. https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-net

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar thing in sftp connector but i have time stamp in file names.
we can try this approach if timestamp or on some basis we can sort the files.
it polls the directory brings all the file names, configured a service override in the connector which sorts the file names based on the timestamp then route. pasting the sample code for reference. we can try similar thing with ftp also.

override the poll() in your service override class

```
public void poll(){
String[] files = sftpRRUtil.getAvailableFiles(false);
List<String> orderedFileList = sortAllFileNamesByTime(files);
Map<String,String> eventStateMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
for (String file : orderedFileList){
if (getLifecycleState().isStopping()){
 break;
}
 routeFile(file);
}
...
```